# Downloading a .xls file php give error code 500

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I have a link on my page that goes to `"basedir/Controls/ProcessExcel.php"`

`ProcessExcel.php` generate an .xls file named `Rapport.xls` in `basedir`. So the path is `basedir/Rapport.xsl`.

The problem is that when I am redirect to `ProcessExcel.php` after it is finish generating `Rapport.xls`I can't get `Rapport.xls` to dowload from server.

Here is the code for `ProcessExcel.php`

```
if($cn-­­>DBConnexion())
{
    //Format stuff here, do stuff there... 
    //This is Validation on my SQLDATA, etc...
}
//Create the .xls file
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($phpe);
//Save the .xls file
$writer->save("../Rapport.xls");

$fullPath = '../Rapport.xls';

if (file_exists($fullPath)) {       
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Rapport.xls"'); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

    readfile($fullPath);
    exit();
}
```

It gives me the error code 500 :

The website encountered an error while retrieving 
http://CantPOSTRealURLSorry.com/basedir/Controls/ProcessExcel.php. 
It may be down for or configured incorrectly.

**EDIT:**
Error in log says:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Can't open ../Rapport.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in C:\basedir\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php:93
Stack trace:
0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\solutions_spb\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(226): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('../Rapport.xls')
1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\solutions_spb\Controls\ProcessExcel.php(224): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('../Rapport.xls')
2 {main}
  thrown in C:basedir\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 93

**EDIT 2:**
I have basicly the same error when trying to send an email with another script. I think both issue might be related.

Comment: check your logs for the real error, maybe a permission issue

Comment: It is a permission issues its said : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Can't open ../Rapport.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in C:\basedir\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php:93
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\solutions_spb\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(226): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('../Rapport.xls')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\solutions_spb\Controls\ProcessExcel.php(224): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('../Rapport.xls')
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\basedir\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 93

Comment: @DevZer0 could you please post your previous comment as an answer? I would choose it.

Comment: thanks for that, i did what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check your logs for the real error, maybe a permission issue